# Find the users based on their distance prefrences

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my MYSQL db and they are:

1. User with columns: `name | email | distancePrefrenceinKM | latitude | longitude`
2. Alerts with columns: `title | description | Latitude | longitude`

What I am trying to achieve is that whenever I insert any alerts in 2nd table, system needs to send the alerts to all the users who comes within their selected range.

If I loop through each and every user, it will take lot of time and wont work as per the expectation.

I have tried to find out the solutions on google but no luck.

I have came across with the following query:

```
set @lng_min = @longitude - @radius/abs(cos(radians(@latitude))*69);
set @lng_max = @longitude + @radius/abs(cos(radians(@latitude))*69);
set @lat_min = @latitude - (@radius/69);
set @lat_max = @latitude + (@radius/69);

SELECT * FROM postcode WHERE (longitude BETWEEN @lng_min AND @lng_max) AND (latitude BETWEEN @lat_min and @lat_max);
```

But again I can not set minimum and maximum range here because every user has different distance preference.

Any suggestions are welcome as I am looking for a optimal solutions.

Regards,
Ashish

Comment: Do your users select distances from a dropdown? If there's a limited number of options you could do multiple passes checking for different users each time. If there are an unknown number of options you may need to take pre-emptive measures, and store the lng_min and lng_max for each user based on their preferences.

Comment: yes user can choose from 1 to 300 km so its not possible for me to check for different users each time.